# SQL Server data drive (.mdf file ) running out of space

Tags: sql-server

What if my SQL Server data drive (where the `.mdf` file is stored) is running out of space?

There is only the `.mdf` file on the drive.

How to free up the space without taking database offline and without any data loss?

Comment: Right Click on Database then  Tasks>Shrink>Databases then check reorganize files before . .. . then click on OK. If there is an empty or unmanaged page, this way you can slightly reduce the size of the database.

Comment: Regarding shrinking the database, I'll point to ShouldIShrinkMyDatabase.com

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. Is this is a hypothetical question? I'm asking because of the wording: _"**What if** my SQL Server data drive (where the .mdf file is stored) is running out of space**?"_ Could you add more details to your question by clicking on [edit]? Things like: SQL Server Version, SQL Server Edition, Disk Size, MDF file size, is it a server, is it a desktop, Database size, single *.mdf file, additonal *.ndf files, ... Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AMtwo Haha, someone finally made a website for that, love it!

Answer (score 7):

There are a few options.

1. Expand the partition in which the data file exists. This is often possible for virtual machines and SAN -attached servers. For stand-alone computers it might not be easy or possible at all.
2. Move database objects to a file that's located on another a disk. This requires another a disk to be present. As with disk expansion, it's simple for virtual machines and SAN -attached servers. For stand-alone computers, a maintenance break is likely required. Moving objects requires DBA planning and effort, be it based on partitioning, moving tables, indexes or other things.
3. Delete data that's not needed anymore. This doesn't free allocated space on the partition, but makes it available for adding new data into the database. This requires input from the business about what data is not needed anymore.
4. Compress data to get better storage efficiency. For older versions of SQL Server, this requires either Enterprise or Developer edition. As of SQL Server 2016 SP1, it's available on Standard edition too. Compressing data is quite simple operation, but it might take a long time and will likely slow down the server during the operation.

As for which option is the best really depends on your environment and use case. I'd start with partition expansion, as it's straight-forward operation and happens entirely outside of SQL Server's scope.

Answer (score 2):

As a last resort, or as a temporary measure until you can *get* more disk storage, which you're going to have to do at some point, you could add [another Data File](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2020/05/31/can-a-database-have-multiple-files-with-extension-mdf-interview-question-of-the-week-279/), on another disk, to your Database.

OK, it's not "recommended", but it is an option to get you to somewhere better.